CAN Transmission not going through
I have a CAN bus set up, my two nodes are the STM32-F429ZIT dev board and a raspberry pi with RS485 CAN hat. I am trying to transmit from the STM32 to the raspberry pi. When I try to run this code, the first three HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage calls are successfully transmitting and the fourth fails (that is, when debugging the code the only the fourth Error_Handler() function would be called). On the raspberry pi, after setting up the raspberry pi according to Waveshare's instructions, none of the CAN messages are being read on the CAN bus, which I checked via can-utils (although the CAN bus does work in loopback mode)
My guess is that the fourth HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage is failing because there are no available Tx Mailboxes for it to use because they are never getting cleared, but I do not know how to remedy this.
Here is the wiring that I am using:

And here are the settings on the stm32


Do you know that CAN and RS-485 do not work with only two data wires, and you need a common ground reference between the two boards, especially if they do not otherwise share a common ground via some other route (like via power supplies or USB cables etc)? Will it work if you add a ground wire?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
